# Using FFT in R to Determine Density Function for IID Sum

Tags: r, fft

The goal is to compute the density function of a sum of n IID random variables via the density function of one of these random variables by:

1. Transforming the density function into the characteristic function via fft
2. Raise the characteristic function to the n
3. Transform the resulting characteristic function into the density function of interest via fft(inverse=TRUE)

The below is my naive attempt at this:

```
sum_of_n <- function(density, n, xstart, xend, power_of_2)
{
  
  x <- seq(from=xstart, to=xend, by=(xend-xstart)/(2^power_of_2-1))
  y <- density(x)
  fft_y <- fft(y)
  fft_sum_of_y <- (fft_y ^ n) 
  sum_of_y <- Re(fft(fft_sum_of_y, inverse=TRUE))
  return(sum_of_y)
  
}
```

In the above, density is an arbitrary density function: for example

```
density <- function(x){return(dgamma(x = x, shape = 2, rate = 1))}
```

n indicates the number of IID random variables being summed. xstart and xend are the start and end of the approximate support of the random variable. power_of_2 is the power of 2 length for the numeric vectors used. As I understand things, lengths of powers of two increase the efficiency of the fft algorithm.

I understand at least partially why the above does not work as intended in general. Firstly, the values themselves will not be scaled correctly, as fft(inverse=TRUE) does not normalize by default. However, I find that the values are still not correct when I divide by the length of the vector i.e.

```
sum_of_y <- sum_of_y / length(sum_of_y)
```

which based on my admittedly limited understanding of fft is the normalizing calculation. Secondly, the resulting vector will be out of phase due to (someone correct me on this if I am wrong) the shifting of the zero frequency that occurs when fft is performed. I have tried to use, for example, pracma's fftshift and ifftshift, but they do not appear to address this problem correctly. For symmetric distributions e.g. normal, this is not difficult to address since the phase shift is typically exactly half, so that an operation like

```
sum_of_y <- c(sum_of_y[(length(y)/2+1):length(y)], sum_of_y[1:(length(y)/2)])
```

works as a correction. However, for asymmetric distributions like the gamma distribution above this fails.

In conclusion, are there adjustments to the code above that will result in an appropriately scaled and appropriately shifted final density function for the IID sum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
dsumf <- function(d, n, a, b, k) {
  x <- seq(a, b, length.out = k)
  p <- d(x)
  s <- sum(p)
  data.frame(x = x, d = Re(fft(fft(p/s)^n, TRUE))*s/k)
}

# use fft to approximate the density of `sum(rgamma(5, 2, 1))`
dsum <- dsumf(\(x) dgamma(x, 2, 1), 5, 0, 32, 2^10)
# plot the approximation against the true density
plot(dsum$x, dgamma(dsum$x, 10, 1), type = "l", col = "blue",
     xlab = "x", ylab = "density")
lines(dsum$x, dsum$d, lty = 2, col = "orange")
legend(
  "topright",
  legend = c("True density", "FFT approximation"),
  col = c("blue", "orange"),
  lty = c(1, 2)
)
```

[image]